# How to calculate $Var(X + 5Y + 1)$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables defined on a finite >probability space $(\Omega, P)$. Assume that 
>   $$
> E(X) = 10, Var(X) = 1, E(Y) = 5, Var(Y) = 4.
> $$
>   I would like to calculate
>   $$Var(X + 5Y + 1).$$

---

I made it this far:

$$Var(X + 5Y + 1) = Var(X) + Var(5Y) + Var(1) = $$

$$Var(X) + 25 Var(Y) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 + 25(E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2).$$

Of course we have $E(X)^2 = 100$ and $E(Y)^2 = 25$, but how do I calculate $E(X^2)$ and $E(Y^2)$?

Comment: Your wrote that $var(X)=1$ and $var(Y)=4$...

Comment: Consider replacing $Var(X)$ and $Var(5Y)=25Var(Y)$ by the numerical values of $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ that **have been given to you**.

Comment: You are given the variances of $X$ and $Y$ directly! In fact, the information about $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ are useless.

Answer (score 1):

Use the result that $Var[aX] = a^2 Var[X]$ and just plug in the values you have.  As Zhanxiong suggests, you do not need the expected value information! You really are a microscopic step away from finishing.

EDIT: Also, use the property that the variance is invariant with changes in location parameter (i.e. $Var[X + c] = Var[X]$).

Answer (score 1):

One step at a time:

- First of all, show that $Var(Z+c)=Var(Z)$ for any random variable $Z$ and constant $c$ to conclude that $Var(X+5Y+1)=Var(X+5Y)$.
- Secondly, by independence (why?), $Var(X+5Y)=Var(X)+Var(5Y)$;
- Note that $Var(X)$ is given. All you need now is $Var(5Y)$;
- Show that $Var(5Y)=25Var(Y)$ and note that $Var(Y)$ is given.